# How do I recreate a map app's logic (like Google Maps) in React.js without using an actual map API

Tags: reactjs, api, maps, logic

I'm working on creating a dynamic map of the factory at which I work. I would like to create a map that can zoom in and out with different elements that will populate depending on the zoom level. I can't find any tutorials that DON'T involve using some sort of maps API to just create a quick maps app. I want to use my own images, my own elements, but with the basic functionality of Google Maps, and I'd like to use React if I can.

Where can I go for this? It's difficult to find anything that talks about the basic "tile structure" coding logic of a zoomable web app that will render different images (in my case would be the "zoomed" images of the same factory) depending on the zoom level. Thanks, any help helps

Comment: How would you get the data for the map then?

Comment: Good question, I would use my own images to map the factory interior itself and manually add the data they want onto the map of the factory. In this case one layer would be IT assets, the other layer would be a map of the electrical wiring throughout the building.